# dropdownlist not working in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-select, yii

the thing is i have 3 models wherein model1  model2's xyz(pid) is invoked which fetches the all id's contain that pid ,know model3 have (id,name) for the model2 fetched ids(fk of model3 id) ,i have looped them ,$data should store the name,id  and a list of all id,name must appear in the dropdown of model1 view create

but i get the error stating

**CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was:**

```
SELECT id,name
FROM table1
WHERE id = Array
```

model1

```
  public function myabcDropDown()
{
    $pid=Yii::app()->SESSION['pid'];

 $sid=model2::model()->xyz($pid);

foreach($sid as $val)   //line 0
{
    $data=model3::model()->pqr($val);
$data.=$data;

}
//line 1
$datalist=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
return $datalist;
}
```

function in model3

```
public function pqr($val)
{
    $sql="SELECT id,name
FROM table1
WHERE id = ".$val;
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
  $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
 $tts=$command->queryRow();
 $result=array();
  foreach($tts as $key=>$val1)
  {
$result[]=$val1;
 }
 return $result;
}
```

function in model2

```
  public function xyz($pid);
{
    $sql="SELECT id
FROM table3
WHERE id = ".$pid;
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$tts=$command->queryAll();
$result=array();
foreach($tts as $key=>$val)
 {
$result[]=$val;
 }
return $result;
}
```

Please help I am losing my mind on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wrks

```
public function myabcDropDown()
{
  $pid=Yii::app()->SESSION['pid'];

$sid=model2::model()->xyz($pid);


$datalist=CHtml::listData($sid,'id','name');
return $datalist;
 }

 public function xyz($pid);
{

$sql="select id ,name from table1 where id IN (SELECT id
FROM table2
 WHERE pid = ".$pid.")";
 $connection=Yii::app()->db;
 $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
 $tts=$command->queryAll();
 $result=array();
foreach($tts as $key=>$val)
 {
$result[]=$val;
}
return $result;
}
```

and no need od pqr() any more

Answer (score 0):

`$result` of `xyz()` is an array of rows(which in turn are arrays of fields) not of fields since `queryAll` was used. Use `queryRow` instead.

Comment: xyz() return list of sid , and each sid has name in model3 which the pqr() retrives.  the thing is $data.=$data; $data when the loop terminate should have list of all sid, name but its not happening so

Comment: Your code doesn't do this. All (xyz) does is return the `$pid` wrapped in an array i.e `array($pid)` since you are getting id where id=$pid. Could you add the relationship between `model1` and `model3`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about **queryScalar()** as they can help you a ;lot. now looking into your code you can do this

```
public function xyz($pid);
{
    $sql="SELECT id
FROM table3
WHERE id = ".$pid;
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$result=$command->queryColumn();
return $result;
}
```

Then

```
    public function myabcDropDown()
        {
             $data=array();
            $pid=Yii::app()->SESSION['pid'];

         $sid=model2::model()->xyz($pid);
    if(!empty($sid))
    {
  foreach($sid as $value)
{
$data[]=model3::model()->pqr($value);
}
       $datalist=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
        return $datalist;
    }
    else
    {
    throw new CHttpException('I got no result');
    }

        }
```

and then finally

```
public function pqr($val)
{
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='id,name';
$criteria->condition='id=:id';
$criteria->params=array(':id'=>$val);
$result=Table1::model->find($criteria);
return $result;
}
```

**Information:-**
**queryScalar()** = You should use it if you are sure that your query is going to return single result only. It will make you free from the headache of arrays. 
**queryColumn()** = You should use it if your are going to select a single column values in your query. It will return you one dimensional array and hence making you free from the headache of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: in your xyz() method your query returns a single value or multiple values?

Comment: multiple values for that pid ..... that was the reason i used foreach to store in data and concatenates whats happening is its store the value for that iteration but doesnt concatenates

Comment: i have made changes in all the three function. so updated all three and tell what you get